# How to create many virtual consoles for msfrpc plugin for python?

Tags: python, ruby, metasploit

I am trying create several virtual consoles with the msfrpc plugin for python. However, whenever I create a new console, I get a back error_backtrace

```
import msfrpc

client = msfrpc.Msfrpc({})
client.login('msf','123')

res = client.call('console.create')
console_id = res['id']

res2 = client.call('console.create')
console_id2= res2['id']
print res2
```

error:

> and res2 ={'error_backtrace':
>   ("lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/rpc_console.rb:15:inrpc_create'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:152:in block in process'",
>   "lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:intimeout'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:152:in process'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:90:inon_request_uri'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:72:in block in start'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/handler/proc.rb:38:incall'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/handler/proc.rb:38:in on_request'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:365:indispatch_request'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:299:in on_client_data'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:158:inblock in start'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:48:in call'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:48:inon_client_data'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:192:in block in monitor_clients'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:190:ineach'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:190:in monitor_clients'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:73:inblock in start'",
>   "lib/rex/thread_factory.rb:22:in call'",
>   "lib/rex/thread_factory.rb:22:inblock in spawn'",
>   "lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:100:in call'",
>   "lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:100:inblock in spawn'"),
>   'error_message': 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)', 'error_class':
>   'ArgumentError', 'error_string': 'wrong number of arguments (2 for
>   1)', 'error': True}`

any solutions? is this the right way or is there any other way to solve this issue? How can I create many consoles?